# Brainfuck interpreter in F#

Tags: f#, interpreter, brainfuck

I have some concerns, like the `updateValue` function. I was trying to follow the functional paradigm, but I wonder if I could use another approach or something.

My parsing function seems overly complicated, particularly the `'['` case seems complicated. Any other comments are appreciated too!

```
namespace Brainfuck

module Interpreter = 
    type public ProgramState = 
        { Pointer : int
          Memory : Map<int, int> }

    let private currentValue state = Map.find state.Pointer state.Memory

    let private updateValue state op = 
        let updateMemory = 
            match Map.tryFind state.Pointer state.Memory with
            | Some(x) -> 
                let m = Map.remove state.Pointer state.Memory
                Map.add state.Pointer (op x) m
            | None -> Map.add state.Pointer (op 0) state.Memory
        { state with Memory = updateMemory }

    type private Command = 
        | SimpleCommand of char
        | Loop of Command list

    let private parse code = 
        let literals = [ '+'; '-'; '>'; '<'; '.'; ',' ] |> Set.ofList

        let rec parsing = 
            function 
            | x :: xs when x = '[' -> 
                let innerLoop, innerRemaining = parsing xs
                let commands, remaining = parsing innerRemaining
                let remainingCommands, after = parsing remaining
                Loop(innerLoop) :: commands @ remainingCommands, after
            | x :: xs when x = ']' -> [], xs
            | x :: xs when Set.contains x literals -> 
                let commands, remaining = parsing xs
                SimpleCommand(x) :: commands, remaining
            | x :: xs -> parsing xs
            | [] -> [], []
        code
        |> Seq.toList
        |> parsing
        |> fst

    let private interpretSimpleCommand state command = 
        match command with
        | '>' -> { state with Pointer = (state.Pointer + 1) }
        | '<' -> { state with Pointer = (state.Pointer - 1) }
        | '+' -> updateValue state (fun x -> x + 1)
        | '-' -> updateValue state (fun x -> x - 1)
        | '.' -> 
            printf "%c" <| (char) (currentValue state)
            state
        | ',' -> updateValue state (fun x -> System.Console.Read())
        | _ -> failwith "invalid command"

    let private compute bytecode = 
        let rec cmp state cmd = 
            match cmd with
            | SimpleCommand(x) -> interpretSimpleCommand state x
            | Loop(xs) -> 
                let nextState = computeProgram state xs
                if currentValue (nextState) = 0 then nextState
                else cmp nextState cmd

        and computeProgram = List.fold cmp
        computeProgram { Pointer = 0
                         Memory = Map.empty<int, int> } bytecode

    let public eval code = 
        code
        |> parse
        |> compute
```

Comment: You could replace `x::xs when x = '['` with `'['::xs` I believe.

Comment: I also think the explicit type parameters on `Map.empty<int, int>` are not needed.

Comment: Wow, the type inference amaze me everyday, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let private currentValue state = Map.find state.Pointer state.Memory
```

This won't work correctly if you try to access memory that hasn't been set yet. Doing that should return `0`, but will instead throw an exception. You can fix that by using `Map.tryFind` together with `defaultArg`:

```
let private currentValue state = defaultArg (Map.tryFind state.Pointer state.Memory) 0
```

---

```
let m = Map.remove state.Pointer state.Memory
Map.add state.Pointer (op x) m
```

You don't need to `remove` before `add`ing the key back in, because `add` will overwrite the old value. (The documentation isn't clear on that.)

This also means you can make your code more DRY by using `currentValue`:

```
let updateMemory = 
    Map.add state.Pointer (op (currentValue state)) state.Memory
```

---

```
let rec parsing =
```

I think that `parsing` is a weird name for a function, function names should be verbs. Since you're already using `parse`, if you can't figure out any better name, you could use something like `parseInternal` or `parse'`.

---

```
| x :: xs when x = '[' -> 
    let innerLoop, innerRemaining = parsing xs
    let commands, remaining = parsing innerRemaining
    let remainingCommands, after = parsing remaining
    Loop(innerLoop) :: commands @ remainingCommands, after
```

This code doesn't make any sense to me. And testing it on [Wikipedia's Hello World program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Hello_World.21) gives me incorrect results. Instead, I think it should look like this:

```
| x :: xs when x = '[' -> 
    let innerLoop, innerRemaining = parsing xs
    let commands, remaining = parsing innerRemaining
    Loop(innerLoop) :: commands, remaining
```

---

```
code
|> Seq.toList
|> parsing
|> fst
```

This means that if you encounter unmatched `]`, you're going to treat it as the end of the file. Is that the correct behavior?

And thinking about unmatched brackets some more, unmatched `[` are automatically closed at the end of the input. Is that correct?

---

```
(fun x -> x + 1)
```

You can shorten this to: `((+) 1)`.

---

```
let private compute bytecode =
```

I think that `bytecode` is a misleading name here, since it's not a code composed of bytes, it's an AST.

---

```
| Loop(xs) -> 
    let nextState = computeProgram state xs
    if currentValue (nextState) = 0 then nextState
    else cmp nextState cmd
```

This is not correct. Brainfuck loops are equivalent to `while` loops, not `do while` loops. The correct code would be something like:

```
| Loop(xs) -> 
    if currentValue state = 0
    then state
    else 
        let nextState = computeProgram state xs
        cmp nextState cmd
```